# Is there a way that i can get the exact data from multi-line TextBox (WinForms) to another TextBox by click on it?

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

In case i want to parse line in multi-line `TextBox` to a few regular `TextBoxes`, by clicking in lets say button, it does for only the 1st line. I didn't see any example of code to get the exact data by clicking on multi-line `textbox`. Usually to get this I use `DataGridView`.

Is this the only way or can i get the same result in multi-line `TextBox`?

Comment: Post some code.

Comment: If there is a solution, i'll be glad to see a code for it.

Comment: So please explain what you are trying to do. Copy content of multiline textBox to regular one?

Comment: @user2982731, Krzysztof is asking for you to post your existing code so we can see what's wrong with it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure, what you mean with 'exact' data. So here are a few thoughs:

1. You can use the `TextBox.Lines` property to access the lines of the textbox.
2. You can use the `TextBox.GetCharIndexFromPosition(Point pt)` function to recieve the index of the char, with the closest distance to the point. Note that the point is in client coordinates of the TextBox.

In general you should look at the documentation of the textbox control: https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.forms.textbox(v=vs.110).aspx .

Comment: I think he means "extract"

Answer (score 0):

Consider using `string[] myLines = nameOfMultiLineTextBox.ToArray();`

This will add each line of your text box to an array which can then be accessed in the form of myLines[0] for line1, and then myLines[1] for line2, etc.